# Is is possible to POST to a URL with Mechanize without opening it first?

Tags: python, http, mechanize

I would like POST to a URL with some form fields filled in with Mechanize in Python. Most code examples like this one:

```
import mechanize

url = "http://duckduckgo.com/html"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False) # ignore robots
br.open(url)
br.select_form(name="x")
br["q"] = "python"
res = br.submit()
content = res.read()
with open("mechanize_results.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(content)
```

first connect to the URL and read the form then fill it in and submit. Is it possible to do this without connecting and reading the form first, if I know what fields are expected?